# Jetpack debug mode enabled, but Woopayments still says I need connection to a public domain to use Jetpack

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Just like it says I have the define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true ); line of code in my wp-config file, and yet when I go to the payment settings for Woocomerce it still says "Your site host "localhost" is on a private network. Jetpack can only connect to public sites." I need to be able to go through the entire checkout system using Woopayments with like dummy credit card info as I develop the site on my local machine if that makes sense.

Tried putting define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true ); in the wp-config.php file